# Bluetooth Low Energy on Linux: Implement a GATT-Client

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I´m new in Bluetooth Low Energy and I´m trying to build my own C-Program on Linux which connects and interacts with an Bluetooth Low Energy Device. For that I'm using the Linux Bluetooth Protocol Stack Bluez.

After reading this blog (https://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/get-started-with-bluetooth-low-energy/) it´s possible for me to connect and communicate with my Device over Command-Line. But now I stuck in doing this with my Code. I looked at the Gatttool Sourcefiles but it´s hard for me to understand..

I tried to connect to the device with gatt_conncect(const char *src, const char *dst,
const char *dst_type, const char *sec_level,
int psm, int mtu, BtIOConnect connect_cb,
GError **gerr), but I think something is wrong with the Arguments which I pass to the function.

```
char dst[] = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"; //device address
char dst_type = BDADDR_LE_RANDOM;
char sec_level = BT_IO_SEC_LOW;
GError *gerr;
BtIOConnect connect_cb; //Compiler says it´s uninitialized, but I don´t in what way I have how to initialize it 
GIOhannel *chan;

chan = gatt_connect(NULL, dst, &dst_type, &sec_level, 0, 0, connect_cb, &gerr);
```

The function crashes. I think something is wrong with connect_cb functionpointer. But after looking in the Gattool Sourcecode I don´t how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Yes. It crahses inside gatt_connect() when bt_io_connect  is called with the given arguments. But the Debugger can´t step deeper into it. It says Segmentation Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Definition for gatt_connect is :

```
GIOChannel *gatt_connect(const char *src, const char *dst,
            const char *dst_type, const char *sec_level,
            int psm, int mtu, BtIOConnect connect_cb,
            GError **gerr);
```

connect_cb is callback function (typedef void (*BtIOConnect)(GIOChannel *io, GError *err, gpointer user_data);)  which will be called when connected. since you have garbage callback probably that’s the reason its crashing!

following is my callback function which I am using:

```
static void connect_cb(GIOChannel *io, GError *err, gpointer user_data)
{
    VVBOX_BLE_DEV_t *pdev = (VVBOX_BLE_DEV_t *)user_data;
    uint16_t mtu;
    uint16_t cid;

    if (err) {
        if (reply_to_listner) {
            mq_send_probe_ble_rsp(listener_id, 0, 5, "");
            reply_to_listner = 0;
        }
        printf("%s failed %s",__FUNCTION__, err->message);
        return;
    }

    bt_io_get(io, &err, BT_IO_OPT_IMTU, &mtu,
                BT_IO_OPT_CID, &cid, BT_IO_OPT_INVALID);

    if (err) {
        printf("%s Can't detect MTU, using default: %s", __FUNCTION__, err->message);
        g_error_free(err);
        mtu = ATT_DEFAULT_LE_MTU;
    }

    if (cid == ATT_CID)
        mtu = ATT_DEFAULT_LE_MTU;

    pdev->attrib = g_attrib_new(pdev->iochannel, mtu, false);
    printf("Connection successful\n");

    gatt_discover_primary(pdev->attrib, NULL, primary_all_cb, user_data);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ah ok thank you! That make sense. Do I have to implement the callback Funktion? 
Where did you find the Definition of gatt_connect? When I look into the gatttool.h file I can only see 8 Parameters. There is no user_data..

Comment: Ahh.. my bad I had modified a bit in my piece of code ;), yes it takes 8!

Comment: Ok I implemented the callback function and pass it to gatt_connect. Seems better now but still crashes.. Do I have to Register the callback function before?

Comment: No gatt_connect() itself registers it. at what point does it crash now ?

Comment: At this point, inside gatt_connect:

    chan = bt_io_connect(connect_cb, NULL, NULL, &tmp_err,
    BT_IO_OPT_SOURCE_BDADDR, &sba,
    BT_IO_OPT_SOURCE_TYPE, BDADDR_LE_PUBLIC,
    BT_IO_OPT_DEST_BDADDR, &dba,
    BT_IO_OPT_DEST_TYPE, dest_type,
    BT_IO_OPT_CID, ATT_CID,
    BT_IO_OPT_SEC_LEVEL, sec,
    BT_IO_OPT_INVALID);

Comment: Is there anything I have to do before calling gatt_connect() ? Or do you have any Idea what I´m doing wrong? That would be very great!

Comment: Before  connect are you scanning ble? You first need to scan and then connect or else it wouldn't connect.

Comment: I´m scanning by using the hcitool source Code (like in this example: https://github.com/glock45/intel-edison-playground/blob/master/scan.c#L35 ). This works. Is this the right way?

Comment: It seems that you solved a Problem really similar to mine "Implementing a GATT Client by using bluez code". Could you provide some Piece of Code? That would be very great. I´m hanging at this Point for about a week and it´s really frustrating

Comment: that will take some to cleanup, have you looked into https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble this should take just minutes to get everything working!

Comment: yes. but it´s in Java script (no experience) and I´m not sure where I have to look to solve my Problem with gatt_connect..?